# GraphError: Invoked API requires Protected API access in application-only context when not using Resource Specific Consent

Tags: java, node.js, azure, api, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to make an api that sends messages to a specific channel or group on teams.

I followed the documentation correctly. In Azure I gave all permissions to my application.
She has the tenandId, clientId and secretId configured, however when I send the request I have this return.

Does anyone know the solution or have experienced this error?

[image]

[image]

Documentantion:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript

Comment: Could you please share the documentation URL which you are referring, so that we can check it from our end.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript

Answer (score 5):

Your code is currently trying to **read messages**, by using a GET HTTP request, which is the `.get()` part in your code.

If **sending a message** is what you want to do, then you need to make a POST request instead, by changing the `.get()` to   `.post(channelMessage)`.

### More on the Protected APIs

According to the ["Protected APIs" documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis):

> Microsoft Teams APIs in Microsoft Graph that access **sensitive data**
> are considered protected APIs. These APIs require that you have
> additional validation, beyond permissions and consent, before you can
> use them.

Personal messages appears to be sensitive data, which makes sense. However, note that there is an alternative solution where you use the API as if the user was using the API. It is called [Delegated permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts#delegated-and-application-permissions).

> Delegated permissions are used by apps that have a signed-in user
> present. For these apps, either the user or an administrator consents
> to the permissions that the app requests and the app can act as the
> signed-in user when making calls to Microsoft Graph. Some delegated
> permissions can be consented by non-administrative users, but some
> higher-privileged permissions require administrator consent.

If delegated permissions isn't an option for you, you can still make a formal request to Microsoft Graph, asking for permissions to use the API without any user interaction.

> To request access to these protected APIs, complete the following
> request form. We review access requests every Wednesday and deploy
> approvals every Friday, except during major holiday weeks in the U.S.
> Submissions during those weeks will be processed the following
> non-holiday week.

[Here is the form for sending a formal request.](https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR1ax4zKyZjVBmutzKVo1pVtUQ1VJMlNTNUdJV1FKTzVZSVU4MlMwTTdOTSQlQCN0PWcu)